# CloudFlare and PTR records for reverse DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, ptr-record

OK so I'm having a hard time configuring reverse DNS for my website protected by cloudflare.

Since cloudflare is protecting my server, it's their IP and NOT the real server IP's that shows up when doing a lookup.

So what do I do ? 
I ask my ISP/hosting provider to do reverse DNS on cloudflare's IPs ?
Those are PTR for www, NOT mailing.

Answer (score 4):

No, those IPs don't belong to your ISP.
They cannot change that, they belong to CloudFlare.

You don't need a reverse DNS record for normal HTTP/HTTPS browsing.
You could contact CloudFlare but I doubt they will configure it.
Those IPs are shared between many customers.